# how to use a numeric field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help fix model .

```
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
from decimal import *


class News (models.Model):
CHOICES_inner_image_position = [
(Decimal ("10.5"), '10 .5% '),
(Decimal ("17.5"), '17 .5% '),
(Decimal (" 30") , '30 % ')
(Decimal (" 33" ) , '33 % ')
]
         
title = models.CharField ( u'Zagolovok ', max_length = 70)
content = models.TextField (verbose_name = u'Soderzhanie ', max_length = 30000)
date_time = models.DateTimeField ()
image = models.ImageField (upload_to = 'news / headimage /')
public = models.BooleanField (verbose_name = u'Opublikovat news ? ', default = True)
teaser_length = DecimalField (verbose_name = u'Kolichestvo characters in the teaser ', max_digits = 4 , decimal_places = 0)
inner_image_position = like = forms.ChoiceField (choices = CHOICES_inner_image_position, widget = forms.RadioSelect ())

class Meta:
verbose_name = ' News '
verbose_name_plural = ' News '
```

I do a console command python manage.py syncdb and get the following error message:

```
NameError: name 'DecimalField' is not defined
```

django1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a `models` in front of your `DecimalField`. The line should read:

```
    teaser_length = models.DecimalField(verbose_name = u'Kolichestvo characters in the teaser ', max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 0)
```